# Symfony2 : can I use find($variable) where $variable is a string?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, dbal

An exception is thrown because of a line in my code:

```
$acadObj = $em->getRepository('ProjectMyBundle:Academie')->find($acadDeleg);
```

where `$acadDeleg` is a string that I retrieve from a data source.

Generally, the official documentation uses `find($id)` where `$id` is a number (an integer). For that, I'm asking if it is possible to use strings. The thing is I have a table from which I have to get a value that I compare with another one, so that I can create an object.

For the record, `$acadDeleg` is the primary key of the `Academie` Entity

EDIT :

The Exception message :

```
The Exception message :

An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t1.codeLieu AS codeLieu2, t1.nomLieu AS nomLieu3, t1.latLieu AS latLieu4, t1.lngLieu AS lngLieu5 FROM Academie t1 WHERE t0.codeLieu = ?' with params {"1":"A"}:

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 't0.codeLieu' in 'where clause'
```

The Academie definition :

```
<?php

namespace PFA\SIGBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Academie
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="PFA\SIGBundle\Entity\AcademieRepository")
 */
class Academie extends Lieu
{

}
```

The Lieu definition :

```
<?php

namespace PFA\SIGBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Lieu
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="PFA\SIGBundle\Entity\LieuRepository")
 */
abstract class Lieu
{

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="codeLieu", type="string", length=20)
 * @ORM\Id
 */
private $codeLieu;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="nomLieu", type="string",nullable=true)
 */
private $nomLieu;

/**
 * @var float
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="latLieu", type="float", nullable=true)
 */
private $latLieu;

/**
 * @var float
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="lngLieu", type="float", nullable=true)
 */
private $lngLieu;
// getters and setters here...
}
```

Comment: What does the exception message say?

Comment: Can you show us `Academie` definition?

Comment: Okay, I've edited the post. Take a look at it :D

Comment: Have you updated your schema recently? (`php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force`) Can you put the relevant part of the definition of `Academie`?

Comment: I just did. What about my question ? Can I use a string as an argument of the function `find` ?

Comment: Your `Id` being `$codeLieu` (a string), you can use it in `find()`!

Comment: Exactly, I wanted to make sure, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your abstract class `Lieu` has to be a `MappedSuperclass`.

You need to change `Lieu` definition to:

```
/**
 * Lieu
 *
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass
 */
abstract class Lieu
{
  //[...]
}
```

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html

Comment: Glad it helped! Don't forget to accept the answer if it helped to solve our problem :)

Comment: Sure, I will ;) I'm stuck with this for two days.. I'll be back here to accept if it helped ;)

Comment: Nicolas, I accepted your answer ! It works perfectly now ! You have no idea how much I'm thankful ! I wanted to vote up your answer, but it says I need 15 points of reputation (I'm poor, only 6 I have). But I'm very thankful. And as I'd say in French "Merci infiniment !"